# Is there someone allergic to Lumosity?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

What is wrong with the question "Can Lumosity exercises really improve core cognitive functions and enhance memory and attention?"

Due to one negative vote & no positive votes after 15 times that the question was viewed, I deleted it.

But, I think there was a good claim; a claim that I have shown by this picture:

[image]

Comment: Lumosity or Luminosity?

Comment: @Sklivvz - Oh my God, Lumosity, sure!

Comment: You didn't even let the question be viewed by more than a few people, so how would you know how the community feels about your question?

Comment: @Sam, I am sure that the better questions are voted up, not down. Neverthless, on the contrary, anybody who has been seriously engaged in scientific work of any kind realizes that I asked a good question here.

Answer (score 6):

1 vote from 15 views is probably fairly normal, you should have left the question up longer to see what anyone else thought of it.

I don't know why your question was downvoted. We have had a couple of questions on brain training:

[Do any brain training video games make you smarter?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1182/do-any-brain-training-video-games-make-you-smarter)

[Does solving Sudoku puzzles improve your mental abilities?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1032/does-solving-sudoku-puzzles-improve-your-mental-abilities)

Possibly the downvoter felt it was a duplicate, although if that was the case voting to close it would be the normal action.

Comment: Perhaps they had enough rep to downvote (125) but not enough to close vote (3000)?

Comment: Hello @Odd, yes, I agree with you. Nevertheless I think that 125 rep-points are not enough to have the privilege to vote down. Skeptics.SE is different from other StackExchange sites. I would say that 1000 rep-points are the minimum that users should have to have that privilege.

Comment: @Carlo_R considering how hard it is to get Rep on Skeptics i think 125 is reasonable. However that is probably better discussed in a different question.